# HTML text input field with currency symbol in the end of it

Tags: css, html, html-input

I would like to have a html5 number input field containing the EUR sign, and no matter what editing occurs to the field, for the sign to be persistent. I tried to do that but the EURO sign is in beginning , I want to move this sign in the  end of the input but for some reasons i can't do it? Any help? [Result](https://jsfiddle.net/xLb9z2po/4/embedded/result/)

My html code:

```
<span class="input-symbol-euro">
    <input type="number" value="0" min="0" step="1"  />
</span>
```

Css code:

```
 .input-symbol-euro {
     position: relative;
 }
 .input-symbol-euro input {
     padding-right:18px;
 }
 .input-symbol-euro:before {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     content:"€";
     left: 5px;
 }
```

Here is jsfiddle : [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/egzontina/x4tek1ro/2/)

Comment: You've set the left position, `left: 5px`, so why is it surprising that the symbol is on the left and not the right?

Comment: in `.input-symbol-euro:before` change `left` to `right`

Answer (score 3):

Why not set `right` instead of `left`:

```
.input-symbol-euro:after {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     content:"€";
     right: 18px;
 }
```

See [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x4tek1ro/5/).  Adjust the value as necessary depending on how far you want it from the end, and set it to a negative value if you want it outside the input.

As you're positioning the element absolutely, `after` and `before` make no difference, although it would be more semantically correct to use `after`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `right` instead of `left`. Which place the content based on the right side of input

```css
.input-symbol-euro {
  position: relative;
}
.input-symbol-euro input {
  padding-right: 18px;
}
.input-symbol-euro:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  content: "€";
  right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<span class="input-symbol-euro">
    <input type="number" value="0" min="0" step="1"  />
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `:after` pseudo class, and position the content from the right side of the box:

```css
.input-symbol-euro {
  position: relative;
}
.input-symbol-euro input {
  padding-right: 18px;
}
.input-symbol-euro:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  content: "€";
  right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<span class="input-symbol-euro">
    <input type="number" value="0" min="0" step="1"  />
</span>
```